# WebAppNotLoadedException : UIleaf not visible

Tags: jsf, websphere

Our application we are currently migrating from Apache Tomcat 7.0 to Websphere 9.0.0.5. We use JSF in our application.

Following is the error we get :

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: org/apache/myfaces/view/facelets/compiler/UILeaf is not visible

com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.exception.WebAppNotLoadedException: Failed to load webapp: Failed to load webapp: org/apache/myfaces/view/facelets/compiler/UILeaf is not visible

Solutions we tried :

1. Added ClassPath in server for
   C:\Users\abcd.m2\repository\org\apache\myfaces\core\myfaces-api
2. In admin console changed class loader to 'classes loaded with local class loader first (parent last)'

But still getting same issue. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Which JSF API version is your app compiled with? WebSphere 9 provides 2.2 at runtime.

Comment: We use myfaces-api and myfaces-impl 2.1.10 in pom.xml.

Comment: Though we use myfaces 2.1.10 jar in m2 repository . In faces-config.xml I have JSF 2.2 version.Can anyone tell me how I should proceed?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0"?>
<faces-config xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
        http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd"
    version="2.2">

Comment: Your faces-config version is fine, but like I've said in an answer it's not fine to mix JSF API and implementation jars. To be clear, are you providing that all of those myfaces 2.1.10 jars inside your application?

Comment: @wtlucy : Have changed all myfaces 2.1.10 jars to myfaces 2.2.0-beta jars .But still getting same error.

Comment: Are you packaging those 2.2.0-beta jars with your app? If you are, you need to follow the answer I gave.  If you just want to use MyFaces 2.2, don't package any JSF jars and just use what WebSphere provides

Comment: @wtlucy : No we are not packaging those 2.2.0-beta jars with our app. In our pom.xml w gave 2.2.0-beta jar and removed myfaces 2.1.0 jar dependency. In websphere classpath pointed to myfaces 2.2.0-beta jar.

Comment: How to use the jars provided by websphere.What are the steps I should follow. Please guide me.

Comment: Websphere classpath refers to 2.2.0-beta jar present in m2 repository.

Comment: `In websphere classpath pointed to myfaces 2.2.0-beta jar.` - do you mean that you've updated the WAS classloader to point to that binary?  If so, get rid of that configuration. To use the JSF provided by and supported by WAS you just need to make sure your app and WAS configuration don't point to any other JSF implementations, ie. `myfaces 2.2.0-beta jar.`

Answer (score 1):

WebSphere provides the MyFaces JSF 2.2 API and implementation at runtime.  If you intend to use a different JSF implementation, then you need to provide the implementation library in addition to the API - in your case, you'd want to provide the 2.1.10 MyFaces impl in addition to the API.

Additionally, the WebSphere docs recommend packaging "third party" (user-provided) JSF implementations in an isolated shared library - see https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_9.0.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/tweb_jsf22.html